# Creating changelog in Liquibase with MSSQLSERVER

Tags: sql-server-2008, jdbc, liquibase, legacy, legacy-database

Hi I am using Liquibase (www.liquibase.org) with SQL Server 2008 project to manage database migration/changes. While using the below liquibase command, I am getting an error "**Unexpected error running Liquibase: Premature end of file.**"

**`liquibase udpate`**

PFB my liquibase.properties file:

```
driver=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
classpath=C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SQL Server 2005 JDBC Driver\\sqljdbc_1.2\\enu\\sqljdbc4.jar
changeLogFile=D:\\Temp\\ChangeLog.xml
url=jdbc:sqlserver://PCNAME\\SQLEXPRESS2012:1433;databaseName=TestDB
username=username
password=password
```

Can you please suggest me how to get rid of this premature end of file error?

Comment: Show us your changelog

Comment: Hi my changelog.xml is new file that I have created.

Comment: And what is the **content** of that file?

Comment: That's empty file I have created.

Comment: Well, you can't run an empty file. There has to be something in there.

Comment: OK thanks for your input. Will try it out and let you know the result.

Comment: It's working fine. Thank you so much :)